# Populate List Data based on selection in InfoPath form on load

Tags: 2013, infopath

I have a subsite named HR.
Whenever HR Office goes to this site they should be able to see the requests for their approvals in a task list.

I want to select any request from SharePoint task list and populate some data on the InfoPath 2013 form.

Any guidelines for my scenario out there?